# RUBY ON RAILS ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound in CarsController#create Invalid single-table inheritance type: Race Car is not a subclass of Car

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[HELP HERE RUBY ON RAILS ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound in CarsController#create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAYZh.png)

Comment: Share the relevant code, instead of the snap.

Answer (score 3):

`type` is reserved column name in Rails. Should be used only in case of Single Table Inheritance (STI). So if you are not using STI then rename that `type` column to something else like `car_type`.

Comment: Or when using a polymorphic association.

Comment: class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :engine
 belongs_to :companies
end

Comment: @darrenaboga Looks like Car model is not using STI , you can rename the column as I answered.

Comment: @max Thanks for the info. I never used only `type` in polymorphic association, always use like `imageable_type` if the association is named as `imageable`. That is what I understood from the Rails guide when I read it first time.